# Printing ToString on new line

Tags: c#, string, winforms, format

I am trying to make a countdown app and would like each time unit to be on a seperate line. At the moment I am able to put the weeks on its own line but the other units are part of a ToString method. 
How would I get each of these onto its own line?

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan ts = chosenDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
        string weeks = (ts.Days / 7).ToString();
        txtTime.Text = string.Format(weeks + " Weeks " + "\n" + ts.ToString("d' Days 'h' Hours 'm' Minutes 's' Seconds'"));

    }
```

It currently prints as:
1 week
5 days 23 hours 13  minutes 45 seconds

Comment: Do exactly the same thing that you did for the line break that worked in the other places that you want a line break.

Comment: Add `\n` where you want a newline to be.

Comment: ... and don't combine strings if you don't have to: `" Weeks " + "\n"` could be just `"Weeks\n"`

Comment: @LarsTech It's a purely aesthetic decision.  It can potentially be easier to read when separated out.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
txtTime.Text = $"{ts.Days} Days{Environment.NewLine}{ts.Hours} Hours{Environment.NewLine}{ts.Minutes} Minutes{Environment.NewLine}{ts.Seconds} Seconds";
```